# "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" when try to Save List as Template

Tags: permissions

When I try to click on "`save list as template`" following error pops up

> Sorry, you don't have access to this page

I have full control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full Control -permission level to your list isn't all that's needed. In addition, you need to have at minimum the permission level **Design** in the **List Template Gallery**. This can be found at **Site Settings** > **List templates**, and you should be granted the permission in here.

Comment: Thank you, but I can see no "List templates" option in site settings. How come is that?

Comment: @Lubos the List templates is only available at the top level of the site collection (that is, the root of the site collection, or yet in other words, the parent site above all subsites).

Answer (score 4):

To reset the default site owner group,  you need to open this setup page "**/_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx**" and either select the existing group or create new group as site owner group.

Select the current site owner group and hit OK.

Refresh IE and it should work.